# icons are not shown in the screen for input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code and I want to show a bootstrap icon instead of a button . Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
 <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default btn-update" />
```

I tried the following and its not working ,any idea how to solve it?

```
 <input type="submit" value="Update" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" />
```

and also like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-remove" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/):

> Don't mix with other components. 
>   Icon classes cannot be directly combined with other components. They should not be used along with
>   other classes on the same element. Instead, add a nested `<span>` and
>   apply the icon classes to the `<span>`.

So try:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Update</button>
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/jfhOqUYFYr)**

Comment: Thakns ,Voted up but I have also the button of the rectangle ,I want just the icons (which should use as button...)any idea?

Comment: Now I'm not clear on what you're after. You want the icon *next* to the button? Like http://www.bootply.com/jyAbQDJyKe?

Comment: Not I just want the icon. I want that the icon act like button but you will not see the button...

Comment: @j08691 Yay, someone actually reads the warnings in our docs for once! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Since the input tag cannot hold any other html in it, the correct way to do this is to use the button tag:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Update</button>
```

[Example in documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples)

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/cMer2DF5FL)

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
input[type=submit] {
        background: url(where_your_image_is);
        border: 0;
        display: block;
        height: _the_image_height;
        width: _the_image_width;
    }
```

OR

```
 <input type="image" src="/yourImage" width ="" height="" border="0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

first download the bootstrap folder :
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.1.1/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist.zip

extract it and upload the files in your server than add to your header :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```